# how to maintain session login until logout is clicked

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

At present if i login then click a link tab on my site then return to the login page i need to re-enter details however i do not want this is want it to store the session until logout is clicked

php login script:

```
<?
session_start();

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db_name = "dblogin";

$db = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die("Connection to database failed, perhaps the service is down !!");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Database name not available !!");

$login = mysql_query("select * from tbuser where (username = '" . $_POST['username'] . "') and (password = '" . md5($_POST['password']) . "')",$db);
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($login);
if ($rowcount == 1) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
header("Location: securedpage.php");
}
else
{
header("Location: loginpage.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for your sessions on every page, including `loginpage.php`

It will work like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])
header("Location: loginpage.php");
```

On your `logoutpage.php`, you just `session_destroy()`

It think that this piece of code will help you

Comment: so every page needs to be .php and that code added to header? currently some are html...

Comment: Yes @Lukus, if you want to use PHP sessions, all your files, that will use session, need to be .php but I you need those files to be .html, you can try usgin HTML5 session storage: http://demos.w3avenue.com/html5-unleashed-tips-tricks-and-techniques/sample-09-sessionstorage-demo.html

Comment: @Lukus It depends on your server and server configuration, but you can also tell the web-server to treat all `.html` files as `php`. Using a `.htaccess` file for example: `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html / AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .html / <FilesMatch "\.(html|php)$"> / SetHandler application/x-httpd-php / </FilesMatch>`. `/` stands for new line.

Comment: @jeroen that is a solution but I don't see a reason to all that just to keep the .html instead of .php, and what if he is using windows?

Comment: @Gerep Like I said, it depends on the server configuration, but I have resorted to this once on a very large site with hundreds of static pages to save time / meet a deadline and avoid seo problems.